# Finishing basement with unusual drainage

Tags: walls, basement, drainage, basement-refinishing

I live in a historic home, and the previous owners made some *interesting* choices, to say the least. As a result, there are lots of things here that I’ve not encountered elsewhere.

I’m currently thinking about re-finishing my semi-finished basement to make it a more comfortable living space. This will likely involve framing stud walls and hanging drywall, but the perimeter wall on 2 sides has a sloped rim around it. The slope comes out about 10” from the face of the wall and is about 6” tall.

It appears to be intended to help channel water away from the walls and toward the sump pump, but we’ve not had any water in the three years we’ve owned the home, despite some local flooding.

[image: Sloped concrete rim around basement floor]

What are my options for finishing the space? I’m open to just about anything. Unfortunately, the room is also an odd shape and has a couple windows above the slope on one end. The already-low ceilings mean I can’t just build the floor above the slope either.

Also, is this a “standard” drainage configuration? I’ve never seen it elsewhere, and I’ve not found any examples online that could help me figure out the finishing question.

Here’s the configuration of the sump pump, in case that’s helpful. There’s a crawl space for an enclosed porch on the other side of the wall behind the freezer.

[image: Sump pump surrounded by sloped concrete with a cut channel for water to enter]

Comment: Is that solid cement, or a hollow channel? If it's solid cement you could just fiddle about with attaching your bottom plate to it with wedges or pouring more concrete to make a flat spot.

Comment: I’m not sure if it’s solid. It certainly feels like it is, but I’m a little afraid of grabbing my sledgehammer to find out.

Comment: The "usual" water channel along the base of the walls leads all the way to the sump pump. Since this does not, there's either a hole in the ends, or not, presumably. No sledgehammer need come into play.

Comment: There are a couple corrugated plastic drain pipes that come into the pit, behind the pump (visible in the second photo). They appear to come from the sloped area, but it’s also possible they come from the crawl space behind the wall. I’ve not been in that space, but I may try to at least gain visual access to it after this weekend’s rain subsides.